# Why "crafty" can not describe a whole plan but "cunning" can?

Tags: word-difference

Below is an expression from the entry "cunning" and "crafty" in Oxford Learner's Thesaurus.

> **Cunning** can describe a person or a plan. **Crafty** usually describes a person;it can also describe a single action, but not a whole plan:
>   -That was a crafty move/touch.(O)
>   -a crafty ploy by the marketing people.(X)

Why cannot "crafty" describe a whole plan but "cunning" can?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why they say that the adjective (crafty) connotation cannot be applied to a plan. Actually usage suggests that the expression "crafty plan" is used as shown in ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crafty%20plan%2C%20cunning%20plan%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrafty%20plan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccunning%20plan%3B%2Cc0).*** I could find no other dictionary that mentions that aspect.

Curiously the usage of cunning in that respect has become more common in recent decades.

Comment: You should look at the results, very many instances of "a cunning plan" are from a British television comedy show *The Black Adder*; "I have a cunning plan" was the catchphrase of Rowan Atkinson's sidekick Baldrick. You should watch the series, the Youtube clips doesn't do it any credit. Hilarious,

Comment: @Mari-LouA Do you mean that what Ngram's statistics suggests is not very trustworthy valid due to the questionable use of "crafty plan" in Youtube? I would like to get your opinion or thoughts on this question. :)

Comment: @SmartHumanism No, I meant that many instances on Ngram are only repeating the catchphrase "I have a cunning plan" and  to watch the entire series of [The Black Adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Adder#Episodes), the clips on YouTube are too brief and they don't really do it any justice.